# Why android give me duplicate ID error when i only have one ID on XML activity?

Tags: android, kotlin

I have an error in Android app with Kotlin while startup an activity
The error is :

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Wrong state class, expecting View
> State but received class
> com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton$SavedState instead.
> This usually happens when two views of different type have the same id
> in the same hierarchy. This view's id is id/left_arrow_btn. Make sure
> other views do not use the same id

The XML part with problem is

```
<Button
         android:id="@+id/left_arrow_btn"
         android:layout_width="24dp"
         android:layout_height="24dp"
         android:layout_gravity="left"
         android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
         android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
         android:background="@drawable/arrow_left"
         android:gravity="left"
         android:visibility="gone" />
```

and Kotlin call to button is

```
var  left_arrow:Button = findViewById(R.id.left_arrow_btn)
left_arrow.setOnClickListener {
                       rWebView?.goBack()
 }
```

Some information:

- Obviously i did triple check that only i have one left_arrow_btn ID
- The error happen  when  calling twice onCreate due to change configuration (like screen rotation) on startup
- I have only one ID left_arrow_btn
- The error occur on Android 13 with Samsung devices ( the app crash on startup)
- On simulator with Android 13/12  and physical Samsung S10/Android 12 work OK ( and on some others  physical devices)

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution:
Change Button for ImageButton and it work.
Very rare error, i don't know why Button cause issues with some Samsung physical devices.